# How to get rid of Error 304 in django?

Tags: django, http-status-code-304

Many times i see "Error 304" in django, but when i google about it i go through many answers which mean that-  "*This does not really indicate an error, but rather indicates that the resource for the requested URL has not changed since last accessed or cached*."

Error-`[20/Aug/2015 17:56:19] "GET /static/dashgumfree/Theme/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 304`

What i noticed is that mostly this happens in case of css and js files,
I just want to know why i am getting the 304 warning if  i have saved the requested file. Also tell me how to get rid of that problem and what is root cause of that error in django.

Comment: You've already got your answer so the real question is why you won't accept it and insist on calling it an "error". The [304 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) means **Resource Not Modified** and indicates to the browser that it doesn't need to request the content again, and can instead use its cached version. This is in no sense an error, and stopping it from happening would be detrimental to the performance of your site.

Answer (score 4):

[304 Not Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) It is not actually an error. It just indicate than the requested resource has not been changed since the last time it was requested and cached. If for some reason you change your `.css` or `.js` files but you don't see the changes reflected in the browser, you can refresh the page with `Ctrl + F5`. It will avoid cached resource and ask them from the server again.

You can configure if the resource are cached or not.

I recommed you take a look to the [Django's docs for this topic.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage)

Comment: Thanks @Gocht for your reply. I have tried Ctrl+F5 but still getting the same problem, My css file is still not updated.

Comment: When you refresh with Ctrl+F5, inspect the browser console (F12 usually) and see in network tab the status of your .css file. It should be 200 OK

Comment: Did you collect static files? @RahulRathi

Comment: We are talking about dev server, I think, right?

Comment: Nope i haven't collected static files yet.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist i run the command- "python manage.py collectstatic"
, but it doesn't cause any file to change.